# Git bash for Windows adds a local directory to remote config command?

Tags: windows, bash, git

I have used Git Bash for Windows to clone a repository from a company intranet, and that repo should also have `remote.origin.uploadpack` and `remote.origin.receivepack`; so basically the procedure looks like:

```
git clone --upload-pack='\/home/windows/dept/REMUSER/git-core/git-upload-pack' ssh://LOCALUSER@.... new_git_folder
cd new_git_folder
git config remote.origin.uploadpack "/home/windows/dept/REMUSER/git-core/git-upload-pack"
git config remote.origin.receivepack "/home/windows/dept/REMUSER/git-core/git-receive-pack"
```

So, the clone passes, but when I do the first push, I get:

```
$ git push --all
LOCALUSER@....'s password:
bash: C:/Program: No such file or directory
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

So, I thought, what the heck - I've never used `C:/Program` anywhere?

Well, it turns out, first: if the argument to `git config remote.origin.uploadpack` is not quoted, as in:

```
git config remote.origin.uploadpack /home/windows/dept/REMUSER/git-core/git-upload-pack
```

... then the command sort of gets completely ignored (that is, when I do `git config -l` in the local repo folder, there is no mention whatsoever of `remote.origin.uploadpack`).

However, when quoted, as in the example above, it seems to write to the config - but it is completely wrong:

```
$ git config -l
...
remote.origin.uploadpack=C:/Program Files/Git/home/windows/dept/REMUSER/git-core/git-upload-pack
...
```

So, even if I specified `git config remote.origin.uploadpack "/home/windows/dept/REMUSER/git-core/git-upload-pack"` - for some reason, I still got the string `C:/Program Files/Git` - which is the local path to Git install - prepended to it?! WHY?! `remote.origin.uploadpack` doesn't even deal with local stuff?!

I've discovered, that if I start the `remote.origin.uploadpack` path value with a backslash, that is:

```
git config remote.origin.uploadpack "\/home/windows/dept/REMUSER/git-core/git-upload-pack"
```

... then this makes the repo (that is, `git push`) work - however, the backslash also ends up in the config:

```
$ git config -l
...
remote.origin.uploadpack=\/home/windows/dept/REMUSER/git-core/git-upload-pack
...
```

So, how should I specify the `git config remote.origin.uploadpack` path command, so that I do NOT get the local Git for Windows installation path prepended to it in the local git config - AND I do NOT end up with a backslash prepended to it either?

This was experienced on Windows 10, `Git-2.19.0-64-bit.exe`

Comment: Hi @sdaau, have you got any solutiion? I'm experiencing the same. :(